# Working on react jsx file and I want to add <link rel="preload" as="image" > on dynamic images that is rendered

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, preload

I have little knowledge in react and the link rel="preload" as="image" href="" usually done in an HTML file in the header tag. How can I add it on jsx file with the images being rendered dynamically as it shows below. I want to preload the mobile images to improve load time

```
<div className="container-image">
                       
                            {sampleImages.length  => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={aush3()}>
                                        
                                        <img src={currentImage.mainUrl + '?$' + smallPreset + '$'} onClick={() => {
                                                setImageViewerVisible(true)
                                                setImageViewerIndex(index)
                                            }}/>

                                    </div>
                                    )
                                })}
                      
                    </div>
```

Comment: For adding/changing tags in HEAD of HTML, you would need something like React Helmet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet